# JS - Change value of all instances of object

Tags: javascript, oop

My instances of some object has some value called `selected` and method `select()`. When method `select()` is fired, I want object's `selected` value to be set `true`, but `selected` value of all other instances of this object to be `false` - how to do it?

In other words - How to change value of all instances of some object?

```
    var Puzzel = function() {
        this.selected = false;
    }; 

    Puzzel.prototype = {            
        select: function{
            this.selected = true;
            //how to set selected = false on every other instance of Puzzel
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can rely on getters/setters (see [compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Cross-browser_concerns)) then the below will work.

This approach has constant overhead when selecting or checking selection, and constant memory overhead.

```
var Selectable = function () {
  // Define your constructor normally.
  function Selectable() {
  }
  // Use a hidden variable to keep track of the selected item.
  // (This will prevent the selected item from being garbage collected as long
  // as the ctor is not collectible.)
  var selected = null;
  // Define a getter/setter property that is true only for the
  // item that is selected
  Object.defineProperty(Selectable.prototype, 'selected', {
    'get': function () { return this == selected; },
    // The setter makes sure the current value is selected when assigned
    // a truthy value, and makes sure the current value is not selected
    // when assigned a falsey value, but does minimal work otherwise.
    'set': function (newVal) {
      selected = newVal ? this : this == selected ? null : selected;
    }
  });
  // Define a select function that changes the current value to be selected.
  Selectable.prototype.select = function () { this.selected = true; };
  // Export the constructor.
  return Selectable;
}();
```

Comment: Im sorry but I dont clearly understand your code, can you comment a little, thank you.

Comment: @MikeSamuel +1 Much better answer than mine.

Comment: I must sit on it for a while :) I dont get how is 'setter' working. Thanks

Comment: @OPOPO, to understand the setter, just keep in mind that when `mySelectable.selected = x`, the setter is called in a way that `newVal` is `x`, and `this` is `mySelectable`.  After that, it's all case-based reasoning.

Comment: I still dont get how it affects other instances... I thought I'm not bad programmer :) Is setter function fired on each instance that has 'selected' prop whenever value of one instance is setted?

Comment: @OPOPO, The setter doesn't need to affect all instances since there is no per-instance state relating to "selected-ness".  `var selected` is declared in the same scope as `Selectable`, so there is one value of `selected` for all instances of `Selectable`.  The question of "is this instance selected?" is only answered when you access the `.selected` property thus invoking the getter which does `this == selectable` to merely check whether `this` is the currently selected instance referenced by `var selected`, so no need to tell instances that were previously selected that they no longer are.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to keep track of those instances. Here's one way of doing it:

```
(function() {
    var instances = [];
    window.MyClass = function() {
        instances.push(this);
        // rest of constructor function
    };
    window.MyClass.prototype.select = function() {
        for( var i=0, l=instances.length; i<l; i++) instances[i].selected = false;
        this.selected = true;
    };
})();
```

Comment: The only way? Isnt is possible somehow to repeat .prototype and overwrite actual values or something?

Comment: This prevents garbage collection of any result of `new MyClass`, requires O(n) overhead on select, and fails if constructors aren't chained.